# Python 3.5 .format() method

Tags: python, methods, format

```
a = 19/3 
print('just testing {a:1.4f}'.format (a))
```

In python 3.5 this results in an error `KeyError: 'a'`.
I cannot understand why. I can use a workaround to overcome the error but I would really appreciate if somebody could explain why am I getting the error.

Comment: print('just testing {0:.4f}'.format (a))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the item before the colon is an index into the arguments of the format() function. See https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.format for more details.

So your example should read:

```
a = 19/3
print('just testing {0:.4f}'.format (a))
```

Alternatively, if you are running python 3.6 or above, you can use f-strings:

```
a = 19/3
print(f'just testing {a:.4f}')
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings for details

Answer (score 1):

Dict-like notation:

```
>>> a = 4
>>> b = 10
>>> 'just testing {num1}, {num2}'.format(num1 = a, num2 = b)
just testing 4, 10
```

Sequencial notation

```
>>> a = 4
>>> b = 10
>>> 'just testing {0}, {1}'.format(a, b)
just testing 4, 10
```

Either use the dict-like notation:
`print('just testing {num}'.format(num=a))`
or the sequential one:
`print('just testing {0}'.format(a))`

Answer (score 0):

```
print('just testing {0:.4f}'.format (a))
```

here the indexing for the variables start with 0.
So if you had another variable Let's say `b=3.142`
the syntax would be :

```
print('just testing {1:.2f} {0:.4f}'.format (a,b))
```